# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near '`'.'

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I'm trying to create a login field using ASP.NET which will take input from the textbox fields and check them against the "user" table in my database. The columns are `User ID` and `Password`. But an error

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near '`'

appears when the login form is used. I don't see any issue with the syntax...

I'm new to this so please excuse me if the error is obvious!

```
public partial class Login_Page : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblErrorMessage.Visible = false;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=JACKS-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=CBR;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
    }

    protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=JACKS-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=CBR;Integrated Security=True";
            con.Open();

            string userid = txtUsername.Text.Trim();
            string password = txtPassword.Text.Trim();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select `user id`,`password` from user where `user id`='" + txtUsername.Text + "'and `password`='" + txtPassword.Text + "'", con);

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            da.Fill(dt);

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                Session["username"] = txtUsername.Text.Trim();
                Response.Redirect("Homepage.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                lblErrorMessage.Visible = true;
            }

            con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: just remove the '`' characters and it will work

Comment: Are you *sure* you're using SQL Server? A Backtick (`\``) is the quote character for MySQL. Also you have 2 **major** problems with your application; the SQL isn't parametrised, meaning it can be injected into, and you're storing your passwords as plain text. Passwords should be hashed and salted. You need to fix those problems before you go any further.

Comment: That is not the correct way to build SQL - use Parameters - and passwords should never be stored as plaintext.  Salt them and and hash them.

Comment: A column name with a space in it like "User id" doesn't work in SQL Server - unless you put it in square brackets. Also, "user" is a reserved T-SQL keyword, so that cannot be use as table name either - unless you put it in square brackets, also. So you need to use: select [user id], password from [user] ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Just remove the '`' characters to make it work.
2. Your code is vulnerable to injection try to add values with `SqlCommand.Parameters.Add()` method.

Use this code:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select userid, password from user where user id = @id and password = @password", con);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtUsername.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtPassword.Text;
```

And as @marc_s mentioned, `user id` is not a valid column name, it should be like `userid` or if it has space in it is should be like: `[user id]`

Comment: A column name with a space in it like "User id" doesn't work in SQL Server - **unless** you put it in square brackets. Also, "user" is a reserved T-SQL keyword, so that cannot be use as table name either - unless you put it in square brackets, also. So you need to use: `select [user id], password from [user] ...`

Comment: I'd suggest adding a note about the password, storing a plain text password is a really bad idea.

Comment: @marc_s yes you are right, actually I didn't saw that.

Comment: That great thanks guys!! That's done the trick. I fear I was following the wrong tutorial online. What difference did parameterising it make out of interest vs injection attacks?

Comment: @Wraithrider well other than that it converts data types itself, you don't need to warp strings between `'` because it knows that it should be done and does itself, for example `cmd.Paramters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;`. but otherwise you have to format datetime to a compatible string format taht sql would understand,...

Comment: @Wraithrider, yes you were following a bad tutorial. With parameters, the SQL statement containing parameter tokens is sent to SQL Server as an RPC request. The request includes strongly-typed parameter values in native form the database engine can use as-is without parsing. Not only does that thwart SQL injection, [parameters provides a number of other benefits](https://www.dbdelta.com/help-stop-sql-injection-madness/).

Answer (score 2):

there are many issues with your code :

1. Do not store plain text password in your program or app config.
2. Do not embed connection string into your program
3. `` ` `` is not SQL Server Syntax.
4. never use string concatenation in your queries specifically if inputs are coming from users. Use Parameterized queries.

.

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select 1 from tbl where id=@id", conn))
{
     var idParameter = new SqlParameter()
     idParameter.ParameterName = "@id";
     idParameter.Value         = 1234; 
     cmd.Parameters.Add(idParameter);

     ....
}
```

5. always dispose objects when you finish your work with them. For this use `using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())`.

   - all methods which implements IDisposable can be used within using statement

Comment: That's a great help thankyou! Yes Plain text is definitely a no go, and will be stored as hash later, but I fear I need to gain some more basic knowledge first from making the other parts of the db first before I bother with the more complex stuff like that!

Comment: Also, at risk of sounding stupid, what is the issue with the embed connection string? and what's a better alternative? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Better to gain experience on SQL side using SSMS and better to code correctly :) If you feel that this answer is helpful for you, please consider to upvote :) thank you

Comment: embedded connection strings needs compilation when you need to change your connectionstring. strings embedded in your application can be easily de-compiled.